# Sorting in Core Data, how to?

Tags: objective-c, sorting, core-data

Currently, I have a core data model that is displayed in a table view. How do I sort the results by `category`, which is one of the entries in the core data model? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you add a sort descriptor (as suggested in a now deleted answer)?

Comment: @danshelly Why did you close your answer? Please reopen it.

Answer (score 4):

Have you read the [Core Data Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/Articles/cdFetching.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002484-SW3)?

The secret is to set a [NSSortDescriptor](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSortDescriptor_Class/Reference/Reference.html) on your [NSFetchRequest](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSFetchRequest_Class/NSFetchRequest.html) by the property you wish to sort by.
For exmple:

**Edit: (the entire example from the docs)**

```
NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [self managedObjectContext];
NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription
                                          entityForName:@"Employee" inManagedObjectContext:moc];
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setEntity:entityDescription];

// Set example predicate and sort orderings...
NSNumber *minimumSalary = ...;
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
                          @"(lastName LIKE[c] 'Worsley') AND (salary > %@)", minimumSalary];
[request setPredicate:predicate];

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
                                    initWithKey:@"firstName" ascending:YES];
[request setSortDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];

NSError *error;
NSArray *array = [moc executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
if (array == nil)
{
    // Deal with error...
}
```

Comment: undeleted as per @flexaddicted request

Comment: Please refer to the supplied links (you set this when you build your fetch request)

Comment: I am getting an error stating the use of undeclared identifier 'request'. Any thoughts?

Comment: Please refer to the supplied links (read the core data introduction at least, and build a default project that use core data to get the hang of things on the basic level)